# What is the best way to write a control in C++ so that it can be used by C++ and C# programs?

Tags: c#, c++, activex, custom-controls

I have a custom control written in C# that I would like to port to C++ because it is too slow, and also because I would like to use it in a C++ program as well as C# programs.

I've looked at MFC Active X, ATL Active X, and .NET C++.  They all seem needlessly complicated.  I'd really like to avoid .NET C++ because involving .NET in a C++ program just seems pointless.

Also there don't seem to be any good tutorials on writing active X controls that aren't a decade old.

Do you guys know of any decent ActiveX tutorials that target Visual Studio 2008?

Is there any other way that I can accomplish my goals without having to write a COM component.  Can I just write a normal control in C++ and stick it in a DLL and have it be usable by both C++ and C# programs?  I don't care about compatibility with GUI form designers.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you should be thinking about your C# implementation before considering jumping back into C++... It running "slow" doesn't say much here, I'm sure it can be improved.  Getting interop to work isn't going to make it easier.

Comment: Don't assume it can be improved.  It does a lot of math on arrays.  Also it needs to be usable by a C++ program.

Comment: Andrew, by normal control I mean either an MFC derived custom control or something written in C for the windows API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My original answer was as follows.  I will leave it here for people in similar situations.

> If C# is slower than C++ for anything other than complex mathematics, you are doing something wrong.  It should be near equal in speed, if not faster.
>
> C++ inherently means making a GUI is going to involve lots of complexity, reinventing of the wheel, and old documentation.  There is no avoiding it.
>
> The fact that "involving .NET in a C++ program seems pointless" indicates to me that you know very little about the technologies with which you are working.
>
> My answer: stick with C#, or you will be in over your head.  Focus on optimizing what you have, not reinventing the wheel.
>
> Edit: As Jeff Mercado said, if you do decide to take a native route, I wish you luck with your interop ventures.

Based on your comment, I am still concerned that you don't understand the role that .NET C++ (recently replaced by C++/CLI) plays.  I think that might just be the perfect solution for you.  It allows you to, say, write an ActiveX control in C++ (which is what I would recommend at this point), and then immediately write a .NET wrapper for it without leaving C++, but instead using a rather large C++ extension.

Yet another addition: Use Visual Studio 2010 if at all possible.  C++/CLI is a huge improvement over its predecessors.  As for ActiveX, don't worry if the guides are old.  It hasn't changed much in the past decade.

Comment: I am doing complex mathematics.  Also the control needs to be usable by a C++ program.  I started writing C programs for the windows API some twenty years ago.  I may not be up on the latest technologies, but I am not in over my head.

Comment: Math on arrays can be very efficient in C#.  Why don't you post a code sample, and I'll see what I can do?  I'll update my answer based on your comment, as well.

Comment: @NXT - Rather than offloading the whole control, you could probably find benefit from only using C++ for the mathematically intense portions of you code.

Comment: The most complicated thing is the fast fourier transform.  There is also extensive use of trigonometric functions.  More to the point, I have to write the application that will use this control in C++.  Sorry I can't post a code sample but I appreciate the offer.

Comment: Got it.  I've edited my answer (yet again) to divide it into the "common" answer for everyone else who lands on this page, and the answer for you.  My answer to you is to use C++/CLI or one of its predecessors.  I think you will find that it rather easy to learn with your background, and it will save you a lot of interop troubles.

Comment: @Zenexer yes, I don't fully understand the interaction of these technologies.  If I can write a .NET wrapper in C++ that would work.  May I ask which technology you recommend, MFC or ATL for creating the ActiveX control?

Comment: @Zenexe, OK, got it, thank you, I am in a better position to google now.

Comment: Good luck!  If you need anymore "keywords", let me know.

Comment: @Zenexer: The C++ optimizer is both more mature than the .NET JIT, it also has more time and therefore includes more complex optimizations.  Templates are far superior to .NET generics in terms of function inlining.  SIMD instrinsics are far superior to .NET array math.

Comment: @BenVoigt I could give you a whole counter-argument to that, but first off, it is worth mentioning that I am not biased toward one language or the other.  I look down on programmers who are, because they usually lack experience in the opposite language, though they usually deny this fact.  Second of all, comments are not really the place for those shenanigans.  I can make either language look better in any context.  It comes down to "which language will fit", and in this case, the answer is C++, so the argument is moot.

Comment: @Zenexer: I use both languages extensively.  C# is very well suited for rapid development and a cheap iteration cycle.  But it has no equivalent to many of the advanced optimizations possible in a language that compiles to native code.

Comment: @BenVoigt C++ has plenty of disadvantages that make it equally suboptimal.  As I already said, this is not the place for discussing them, but to give you a simple example, a JIT can utilize optimizations available to a specific machine, while an AOT cannot.  Both C# and C++ have an AOT compiler, but C++ lacks a JIT compiler.  Think of JIT compilation as an optimization refactor.

Comment: @Zenexer: These are theoretical optimizations that the .NET JIT doesn't do.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7329/discussion-between-zenexer-and-ben-voigt)